# Javascript/JQuery to sort alphabetically a list with anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, anchor

I have this list:

```
<ul id="demoOne" class="demo">
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1154'>Dhenie fotokopje aktesh nga dosja 12</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1155'>Depozitim kerkesash Ankimore/Rekurse
        kunder vendimeve civile/penale 12</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1156'>Dhenie Vendimesh12</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1157'>Integrimi i Ish te Perndjekurve Polikite
        12</a> </li>
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1158'>Dhenie Drejtesie</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://site/Service.aspx?shId=1159'>Gjykata e Rrethit Gjyqësor Lezhë ushtron
        juridiksionin gjyqësor civil dhe penal në territorin e qarkut Lezhë të Republikës
        së Shqipërisë.</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to alphabetically sort this list, using the anchor text, not the li text.
How to do that?

I'm using this script to sort them by li text

```
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
        var items = $('.demo li').get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){ 


          var keyA = $(a).text();
          var keyB = $(b).text();

          if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
          if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
          return 0; 

          var keyA = $(a).text();
          var keyB = $(b).text();

          if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
          if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
          return 0;

        });
        var ul = $('.demo');
        $.each(items, function(i, li){
          ul.append(li);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it when using the li? If you do you should just change the identifier to $("li a")

Comment: $("li a") - this is bad way, it takes too long to work. You better add some class to all needed anchors and then pick em with $(".anchorClass").

Comment: How is this HTML code generated? Can't you sort in there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.sortList = function() {
    var mylist = $(this);
    var listitems = $('li', mylist).get();
    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : 1;
    });
    $.each(listitems, function(i, itm) {
        mylist.append(itm);
    });
   }

    $("ul#demoOne").sortList();

});
```

Comment: I'm giving this as the right answer cause it is working on IE too. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sort` method.

```
$('#demoOne li').sort(function(a, b){
     return $('a', a).text() > $('a', b).text()
}).appendTo('#demoOne');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3jfF/

Comment: I think that the custom sort function must return 1, 0, or -1. A boolean works on Firefox, but not on Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: you may want to use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to get all the `li`. Then use  [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) to get a javascript native array. And you can sort your array using the `sort` method and providing a sort function corresponding to your needs.

Comment: Out of the box, I don't think this will work. Maybe a code sample?